# Using FileServer to serve my single html page

Tags: http, rest, go

I'm trying to build a sample web application demonstrating [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) techniques using [go](/questions/tagged/go) at the back-end, serving [json](/questions/tagged/json) based requests and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) in the front-end (I'm not using `html/template` package).

[FileServer](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) `"returns a handler that serves HTTP requests with the contents of the file system rooted at root."`

supose that I'm publishing my `static` folder that contains `index.html` and `scripts` folder holding some `javascript`  files.

How can I prevent the client from viewing my `js` files (publishing just the `index.html` at `/`) ?

Comment: What's the use of that? Not being able to access the JavaScript means that the browser can't download the js files, and thus not execute them.

Comment: @nemo  `the use of that?` I don't know (just wondering) , My first steps in web programming, can you recommend some resources ? (should I delete the question ?).

Comment: No, you should not delete your question. It's a valid question and it may be easily transferred to filtering arbitrary files from `FileServer`. I was just wondering if I understood you correctly and you know what you're doing. There are plenty of projects for web stuff in go, [gorilla](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/) or [revel](http://robfig.github.io/revel/) for example.

Comment: Thanks @nemo , I just want to start by using just `,net/http` and `html/template` built-in functionality provided by the `go` core packages , so my plan is to understand my `html` well, the idiomatic way to build a modern web app (using rest techniques, more code on the client side and less `html` templates), and then I will move the next step by using one of go web frameworks available, you said that you can filter and transfer files from `FileServer` How ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily restrict the `FileServer`, which is a `HttpHandler` by wrapping another `HttpHandler` around that. For example, take this wrapper which ONLY allows `*.js` files to be served:

```
func GlobFilterHandler(h http.Handler, pattern string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        path := r.URL.Path

        fileName := filepath.Base(path)

        if ok, err := filepath.Match(pattern, fileName); !ok || err != nil {
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Error in pattern match:", err)
            }

            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    fileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp/dtest"))
    wrappedHandler := GlobFilterHandler(fileHandler, "*.js")
}
```

You can find a blog post [here](http://www.capotej.com/blog/2013/10/07/golang-http-handlers-as-middleware/) which describes the basic idea pretty good.

Another option you have is to extend on `http.Dir` and make your own `http.FileSystem` implementation which does exactly what you want:

```
type GlobDir struct {
    Dir     http.Dir
    Pattern string
}

func (d GlobDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    baseName := filepath.Base(name)

    if ok, err := filepath.Match(d.Pattern, baseName); !ok || err != nil {
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s not match GlobDir pattern.", baseName)
    }

    return d.Dir.Open(name)
}

func main() {
    fileHandler := http.FileServer(GlobDir{
        Dir: http.Dir("/tmp/dtest"),
        Pattern: "*.js",
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", fileHandler)
}
```

The second solution implements the `http.FileSystem` interface which is accepted by `http.FileServer`.
It checks whether the input file name matches the supplied pattern and then hands control down to the original `http.Dir`. This is probably the way you want to go here.

Comment: Thanks @nemo , I will try both of these solutions.